# Simple JS calculator with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I found subjects like mine but I couldn't fix my problem after reading them, So I wanted to make a simple calculator using JS but I couldn't do it and it keeps doing nothing ! I think the main problem is with the radio buttons.

Can you help me, it's kind of easy I know but I'm still a beginner. 
PS: I don't want jquery!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercice1 | JS</title>
    <script>
        function calcul (op, v1, v2){
                if (document.f.op[1].cheked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) + parseInt(v2.value));
                if (document.f.op[2].cheked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) - parseInt(v2.value));
                if (document.f.op[3].cheked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) * parseInt(v2.value));
                if (document.f.op[4].cheked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) / parseInt(v2.value));
            }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name ="f" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="v1">Var 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="v1" id="v1"></input>
        <br> <br>
        <label for="v2">Var 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="v2" id="v2"></input>
        <br><br>

        <input type="radio" name="op" value="1"></input>
        <label for="1">+</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="2"></input>
        <label for="2">-</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="3"></input>
        <label for="3">*</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="op" value="4"></input>
        <label for="4">/</label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="calcul(op, v1, v2)" value="Calculate"></input>
        <input type="reset"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that could fix off my head:

Do not pass op, v1, v2 in your calcul function, and change your function to  function calcul () because you've used those three - (op, v1, v2) to declare your elements' name's anyways - variables with the same names are accessible in your function anyways

cheked is incorrect, it's .checked

```
    function calcul (){
                    if (document.f.op[0].checked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) + parseInt(v2.value)); 
// you are accessing an array - so index starts with Zero
                    if (document.f.op[1].checked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) - parseInt(v2.value));
                    if (document.f.op[2].checked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) * parseInt(v2.value));
                    if (document.f.op[3].checked) alert(parseInt(v1.value) / parseInt(v2.value));
                }
```

Change this too:

```
onclick="calcul()"
```